# Android emulator'graphics in software mode break gui

Tags: android, emulator

i'm current building an app using cordova with reactjs. Everything went well except for this particular (not major) issue i had when run the app on android studio'emulator. When creating virtual device, i chose "software" for the emulator's graphic, but it broke my app gui, however when i create another virtual device, but this time choosing "hardware" instead, it backs to normal.

Here are the screenshots:

[this is the device with graphics set to hardware mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeRQn.png)

[this is the device with graphics set to software mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJwA0.png)

Comment: I don't see a difference...

Comment: Hi, it seems that i uploaded the same photo, i reposted it. maybe you can look at it again.